# Next JS & Prisma TypeError: posts.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

I'm working with Prisma in Next JS for the first timeand i've been getting this error.
I'm importing data from prisma client in my dynamic page and i'm using simple code here.

Here is my code:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { Container, Div1, Div2, Div3 ,Button , Input ,Label } from '../../components/Header/HeaderStyles';
import {useState} from 'react';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export default function Details({posts}) {
    return (
            <div>
                {posts.map((post) => (
                    <div key={post.id}>
                        {post.id} {post.text}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const { id } = context.query 
    const data = await prisma.contact.findFirst({
        where: {
            id: Number(id)
        }
    })
    return{
        props:{
            posts:data,
        }}
}
```

Comment: `map` is an array function. `findFirst` only returns one object/record from the database. That's why posts.map() is not a valid function call as there's only one `post`.

Comment: Happy to help :)